# How can I test a click event is canceled with playwright

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright, eventemitter, stenciljs

I'm building a base level componenet(like a button) which can be removed when clicking in the closable icon in that compoenet, I want to test :
There should be one click event emitted followed by one myClose event. If click is cancelled then myClose is not emitted and the componenet won't be removed from the DOM.So I wanted to make sure that the compoenent is removed from the DOM unless the click event is cancelled.
How to do so with playwright e2e test?

I tried to make a sénario where I access to the icon with playwrite css selector , click it and expect that the event will be emitted just once and the componenet won't be removed but the test fail (ofcours because I didn't cancel the event click, how to cancel it in test?)

```
  test(`myTest`, async ({ page }) => {
    const content = 
      <my-button
        text="Button"
        type="closable"
      ></my-button>

    await setupPage(page, { content, addBrandFont: true })

    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const closableButton = document.querySelector('.my-button[type="closable"]')
      closableButton?.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('myClose', { cancelable: true }),
      )
    })
    await page.locator('css=my-button[type="closable"] .my-icon').click()

    await page.waitForSelector('.my-button[type="closable"]', {
      state: 'detached',
      timeout: 2000,
    })
    const closableButton = page.locator('my-button[type="closable"]')
    const myCloseSpy = await closableButton.spyOnEvent('myClose')

    expect(myCloseSpy).toHaveReceivedEventTimes(0)

    const isClosableButtonVisible = await page.isVisible(
      'my-button[type="closable"]',
    )
    expect(isClosableButtonVisible).toBeTruthy()
  })
```

Comment: Can you share the page you're automating? This test looks unusual. Asserting that an event occurred 0 times one line after spying on it seems like a self-evident "always pass". Usually you don't need to dispatch or add custom events to things to make sure the site is behaving correctly.

Comment: I'm testing a small component in the storybook

Comment: Please share that actual component so I can run the site, examine the behavior, then run your code and see the failing test. I can't write a test for a page I can't see.

Comment: I'm currently testing a small component within Storybook. My expertise in testing is limited, but my objective is to experiment with event handling. Specifically, I aim to simulate a scenario where a click event is cancelled (using preventDefault) and observe whether the button remains in the DOM or not. Ordinarily, clicking on the icon triggers the removal of the button from the DOM. However, I wish to verify whether preventing the default behavior will result in the button persisting

Comment: Thanks for that, but it still doesn't help me help you. I need the page or a runnable [mcve] of it to be able to provide any help here.

Comment: the idea here is to know how to cancel the default behavior of my event inside the test so I can see if I have the expected result.do you have an idea how to do that? and is it the correct approach?